# How to decompress string retrieved from server using gzip

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, compression, gzip

I was given a problem which involves retrieving a string from a server using a GET_key and then decompressing it. After a while I figured out it was gzip compression but I am having problems with my python code. Here is my problem:

> Write a script which can connect to the following server: 'localhost', 10000 over TCP send GET_KEY to download a string. The string is compressed with a common algorithm found in many websites. Uncompress the string and print it to get the flag.

The first part of my code works fine:

```
import socket
import gzip
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 10000))
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n")
data = s.recv(4096)
```

And produces the result:

```
ƫ\ OQHKU(HUHILW,Rt r
5
vR|)&
```

However when I try to decompress it I run into errors. Here is my full code:

```
import socket
import gzip
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 10000))
s.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n")
data = s.recv(4096)
fil =gzip.GzipFile(data)
print (fil.read())
```

Which produces an error stating: *TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str*

Looking up this error gave me nothing related to my specific problem so I must be doing something wrong and furthermore I cannot use `gzip.decompress`
as I am using python 2.7 How do I decompress the string without any errors occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gzip.GzipFile` constructor expects a file name as the first argument, so your `data` is treated as a file name rather than compressed data when you call `gzip.GzipFile(data)`.

You should create an `io.BytesIO` object from `data` and use the `fileobj` argument to instantiate `gzip.GzipFile` instead:

```
from io import BytesIO

fil = gzip.GzipFile(filobj=BytesIO(data))
```